# @media (max-width: 576px) is not working for desktop browser

Tags: css, flexbox

I have following html code for catalog output using flex

```
      <div class="page__content-block">
        @foreach ($item->children as $item)
        <a href="#" class="catalog__card">
          <div class="catalog__card-img"><img src="#"></div>
          <div class="catalog__card-title"><span>{{ $item->title }}</span></div>
        </a>
        @endforeach
      </div>
```

then css

```
.page__content-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-basis: auto;
  a:nth-child(2), a:nth-child(3) {margin-left: 25px;}
  @media (max-width: 992px)  { a:nth-child(3) {margin-left: 0;}  }
  @media (max-width: 576px)  { a {margin-left: 25px;}  }
}
.catalog__card {
  display: block;
  align-self: stretch;
  order: 0;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 285px;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  @media (max-width: 992px)  { width: 40%; }
  @media (max-width: 576px)  { width: 100%; justify-content: center; }
  &:hover .catalog__card-title {background: #2690ca;}
}
```

And when I resize browser below 576px then I see 2 catalog__cards in one row, though I expect to see just one.
But when I open same page in Responsive web design tester for Chrome I see one catalog__card per row.
Why it is so?

Here is screenshot

[image]

Comment: Is that really your **CSS** style? Are you sure it's not sass?

Comment: @AlonEitan this is the SASS code not normal css code.

Comment: Correct. It is SASS code. But in the end it is compiled in CSS

Answer (score 0):

`@media (max-width: 576px)` is working for the screen less then `577px`.

you have to use `@media (min-width: 576px)` for apply css greater then `575px` screen.

Comment: Please check my question properly. If you studied attached screen shot you can see that I have chrome window 500px width and anyway style `@media (max-width: 576px)` is not applied  for that window - I have 2 items per row instead of one item, whereas on the right side of screenshot I have Responsive web design tester for Chrome window 350px width with one item per row. How it is possible?